# best way to do laravel multi auth

Tags: laravel

I wonder, which way is the easiest and the best for making multi auth (admin and also multiple type of users) for Laravel. Is it okay to put them all in `users` table and then use field `role` to check their privilege via if statement? Or I need to make guard or middleware for admin?

Comment: The best way is to add column of role into your users table with enum type 
and for routing made middleware and pass every route through that middleware redirect every route according to their role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it that way or any other way you want. It all depends on needs.

If you want to build something that can scale and grow, I think this is the best practice:

All users in `users table`, new `table for roles` and a pivot table `role_user`. This way a user can have multiple roles or just one (doesn't matter).

Make a middleware if you need to protect admin area for example.

Make Policy if you need to protect certain actions in controller.